# check filesystem file consistency against db

Tags: php, mysql, readdir, scandir

I have a PHP script that uploads files to a directory on my filesystem. On the same time I store the filename in a field on a MYSQL DB.

I have seen that I have more files than records in the db.

What's the shortest way to find out and delete all those files that are not linked to a record on the DB? My idea would be to read each filename from the directory, run a query on the db with the filename taken from step 1 and in case the query returns 0 result to delete the file.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Lelio

Comment: Fetch all filenames from DB into set A, fetch all filenames from the filesystem into set B, delete the ones from set B that are not present in set A.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php check here and also here http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the files in the folder using `scandir`, and use the `NOT IN` clause to remove the files not in the folder.

```
$files = implode(scandir('files/'), "', '");
$db->query("DELETE FROM files WHERE file_name NOT IN('{$files}')");
```

If you want to do the opposite and delete the files which don't link up to a record in the database you can use a function called `unlink`. This will delete the file. There's probably more optimized versions, but this is what I would do:

```
$files = implode(scandir('files/'), "', '");
$sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE file_name NOT IN('{$files')");

foreach($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $file) {
    unlink("files/{$file_name}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about implode, I'll give it a try. Only one more question: as far as I understand the foreach loop will delete those files that are both in the db and in the filesystem or I am missing something??

Comment: It will list all the files in the folder, if one of them is `NOT IN` the database it will delete it. There was never a record in the DB to delete.